# What does Opencl make_Kernel actuatlly return and how do i store it?

Tags: c++11, opencl

I have the following code below, where I am trying to store my kernel that I compiled into a variable functor that can then be accessed later. Unfortunately, when I declare auto kernelTest in the struct, it throws an error saying that "non-static member declared as auto". What does cl::make_kernel actually return, and how can I store it as a private variable?

```
struct OCLData
{
    cl::Device device;
    cl::Context context;
    cl::CommandQueue queue;

    cl::Program program;
    auto kernelTest; (PROBLEM)

    const char *kernelTestSource = MULTILINE(
    __kernel void kernelTest(const int N, __global float* A, __global float* B, __global float* C)
    {
       int i = get_global_id(0);
       int j = get_global_id(1);
    }
    );

    OCLData(){
        try{
            // Set Device
            cl_uint deviceIndex = 0;
            std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
            unsigned numDevices = getDeviceList(devices);
            if (deviceIndex >= numDevices)
            {
            std::cout << "Invalid device index (try '--list')\n";
            return;
            }
            this->device = devices[deviceIndex];

            // Set Context and Queue
            std::vector<cl::Device> chosen_device;
            chosen_device.push_back(device);
            this->context = cl::Context(chosen_device);
            this->queue = cl::CommandQueue(context, device);

            // Print Device Name
            std::string name;
            getDeviceName(this->device, name);
            std::cout << "\nUsing OpenCL device: " << name << "\n";

            // Compile GPU Code
            this->program = cl::Program(this->context, this->kernelTestSource, true);
            //auto kernel = cl::make_kernel<int, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer>(this->program, "kernelTest");
            this->test = cl::make_kernel<int, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer>(this->program, "kernelTest");
            //cl::make_kernel<int, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer> naive_mmul(this->program, "kernelTest");
            std::cout << "GPU Code Compiled: " << "\n";

        } catch (cl::Error err)
            {
            std::cout << "Exception\n";
            std::cerr << "ERROR: "
                    << err.what()
                    << "("
                    << err_code(err.err())
                    << ")"
                    << std::endl;
            }

    }
};
```

Comment: Don't know, what it creates, but you can create a member variable of the proper type by using decltype.

Answer (score 1):

`cl::make_kernel<int, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer>` creates object of that type.

According to C++11 standard `auto` class member must be also `static const` which means it must be initialized however there is quite a bit of the code to be executed before `cl::make_kerenl<...>` could be created.
In this case you can use `std::shared_ptr` as a member type of the struct:

`std::shared_ptr<cl::make_kernel<int, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer>> kernelTest;`

and then later in the code:

`this->kernelTest.reset(new cl::make_kernel<int, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer, cl::Buffer>(this->program, "kernelTest"));`

Answer (score 1):

I did this as suggested by a friend:

```
typedef cl::make_kernel <float, cl::Buffer&> kernelTestType;
std::function<kernelTestType::type_> kernelTest;
this->kernelTest = kernelTestType(this->program, "kernelTest");
```

Looks like this works